# using simple unittest mock to patch an SMTP call

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I'm just in the process of learning about unittest Mocks and trying to understand why patching a call to 'smtplib.SMTP' is not returning the value that is set on the mock object. I assume it is not, as assertion is failing.

I have a simple definition of a function to send an email:

```
def send(sender, to, subject="None", body="None", server="localhost"):
    message = email.message.Message()
    message['To'] = to
    message['From'] = sender
    message['Subject'] = subject
    message.set_payload(body)

    server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    try:
        server.sendmail(sender, to, message.as_string())
    finally:
        server.quit()
```

I have a unittest file that contains a simple test function:

```
def test_send():
    with patch('smtplib.SMTP') as mock:
        instance = mock.return_value
        instance.sendmail.return_value = {}
        res = send('x@gmail.com', 'y@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body')
        assert res == {}
```

As I understand, when the sendmail of the 'smtplib.SMTP' is called, that call should be patched by mock and should return an empty dict. So the res variable should be set to {}.

When executing pytest against the file, that assertion always fails:

```
 assert None == {}
```

I have two questions:

1. is there something amiss with my definition of the unittest?
2. what is a good approach to debugging this type of issues. I tried running pytest with --trace option, but couldn't capture the 'patching' moment when stepping through code.

Comment: Could you share your file tree?

Comment: `patch` needs to specify the thing you're patching *in terms of the context you're patching it in*.  Is `send` defined in the same file as `test_send`, or is it defined in another file/module?

Comment: `send` is defined in a different module that is imported into test module. I don't thin that this is an issue here, since it would be normal to have functions defined in a different module to the one where they are tested.

Comment: Could you please add the import statements for the mock in the code snippet for better understanding about the module. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
res = send('x@gmail.com', 'y@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body')
assert res == {}
```

You are expecting that `send` would return a value and that should be the mocked value of `{}`. Yet, you defined your implementation to not return anything

```
def send(sender, to, subject="None", body="None", server="localhost"):
    ...
    try:
        server.sendmail(sender, to, message.as_string())
    ...
    # Doesn't return anything
```

If you want to see the mocked value, then you should respond back the return of the call to sendmail.

```
def send(sender, to, subject="None", body="None", server="localhost"):
    ...
    response = None
    try:
        response = server.sendmail(sender, to, message.as_string())
    ....
    return response
```

The test was successful on my side after running it.

Comment: you are right, since i was not returning anything from `send`, it would be None. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped you. If it's all the answer you need, you might want to accept it as the answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers